# Regex: How to match pattern only once?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to extract data from a .config file (generated by using kconfig).
The default format is:

```
SYMBOL=y (in case of a bool)
SYMBOL="str" (in case of a string)
```

I did managed to get it working with the following regex:

```
sed -e '/^#/d;s/\(.+\)=\(.+\)/def \1 "\1"\n/g' configfile > formattedfile
```

It is working for any case except for this one:

```
SYMBOL="http://my.domain/toast?id=150"
```

As a result, I have in my output file:

```
def SYMBOL="http://my.domain/toast?id "SYMBOL="http://my.domain/toast?id="
```

Because the pattern XXX=XXX appears twice in this line.
How can I avoid this please ?

Regards,

Comment: change first `.+` to `[^=]+`

Comment: It is no longer matching now.

Comment: is `def SYMBOL "SYMBOL"` your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` symbol and also turn the first `.+` to `[^=]\+` because `.+` is greedy and matches upto the last `=` symbol.

```
$ sed -e '/^#/d;s/\([^=]\+\)=\(.\+\)/def \1 "\1"\n/g' file
def SYMBOL "SYMBOL"

def SYMBOL "SYMBOL"

def SYMBOL "SYMBOL"
```

Comment: @Lazao i'm the first to post this. And also you need to escape the `+`, so that it would repeat the previous token one or more times.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I changed the acceptance tag. Thank you Avinash.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.+` is **greedy**: it tries to match the longest possible string. This extends to the second `=`. Since identifiers can't contain a `=` character, it is best to be more specific in matching the first part:

```
sed -e '/^#/d;s/^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/def \1 \2\n/' configfile > formattedfile
```

Note that I changed the second `\1` to `\2` since I think this is what you meant. I also avoided the extended regular expression quantifier `+` in favor of the basic regular expression quantifier `*` which is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the `g` in your command:

```
sed -e '/^#/d;s/\(.+\)=\(.+\)/def \1 "\1"\n/'
                                            ^
```

instead of

```
sed -e '/^#/d;s/\(.+\)=\(.+\)/def \1 "\1"\n/g'
                                            ^
```

From `info sed`:

```
`g'
     Apply the replacement to _all_ matches to the REGEXP, not just the
     first.
```

See another example:

```
$ echo "hello" | sed 's/l/X/'   #without g
heXlo
$ echo "hello" | sed 's/l/X/g'  #with g
heXXo
```

Comment: The global modifier is not the problem. The greediness of `.+` is the problem.

Comment: I see, well done @Jens ! Just leaving this solution here since it may help other people entering the question with the problem described in the title.